# Interacting with libscap from Python using ctypes

Tags: python, c, shared-libraries, ctypes

I have been working on a wrapper around sysdig libscap library using ctypes. It is all working good except one thing that is starting to frustrate me. Libscap uses the uthash library for implementing hash table like data structures in C language. I have this declarations for structures used by [uthash](https://github.com/draios/sysdig/blob/master/userspace/libscap/uthash.h).

```
if sizeof(c_void_p) == 4:
     ptrdiff_t = c_int32
elif sizeof(c_void_p) == 8:
     ptrdiff_t = c_int64


# uthash.h
class UT_hash_table(Structure):
    pass
class UT_hash_handle(Structure):
    pass
UT_hash_handle._fields_ = [ ("tbl", POINTER(UT_hash_table)),
                 ("prev", c_void_p),
                 ("next", c_void_p),
                 ("hh_prev", POINTER(UT_hash_handle)),
                 ("hh_next", POINTER(UT_hash_handle)),
                 ("key", c_void_p),
                 ("keylen", c_uint),
                 ("hashv", c_uint)]

class UT_hash_bucket(Structure):
    _fields_ = [ ("hh_head", POINTER(UT_hash_handle)),
                 ("count", c_uint),
                 ("expand_mult", c_uint)]

UT_hash_table._fields_ = [
                 ("buckets", POINTER(UT_hash_bucket)),
                 ("num_buckets", c_uint),
                 ("log2_num_buckets", c_uint),
                 ("num_items", c_uint),
                 ("tail", POINTER(UT_hash_handle)),
                 ("hho", ptrdiff_t),
                 ("ideal_chain_maxlen", c_uint),
                 ("nonideal_items", c_uint),
                 ("ineff_expands", c_uint),
                 ("noexpand", c_uint),
                 ("signature", c_uint32),
                 ("bloom_sig", c_uint32),
                 ("bloom_bv", POINTER(c_uint8)),
                 ("bloom_nbits", c_char)]
```

There is also another structure [scap_threadinfo](https://github.com/draios/sysdig/blob/master/userspace/libscap/scap.h), which acts as hash table, and holds the list of processes parsed from /proc filesystem.

```
class scap_threadinfo(Structure):
        _fields_ = [ ("tid", c_uint64),
                     ("pid", c_uint64),
                     ("ptid", c_uint64),
                     ("comm", c_char * SCAP_MAX_PATH_SIZE),
                     ("exe", c_char * SCAP_MAX_PATH_SIZE),
                     ("args", c_char * SCAP_MAX_PATH_SIZE),
                     ("args_len", c_uint16),
                     ("env", c_char * SCAP_MAX_ENV_SIZE),
                     ("env_len", c_uint16),
                     ("cwd", c_char * SCAP_MAX_PATH_SIZE),
                     ("fdlimit", c_uint64),
                     ("flags", c_uint32),
                     ("uid", c_uint32),
                     ("gid", c_uint32),
                     ("vmsize_kb", c_uint32),
                     ("vmrss_kb", c_uint32),
                     ("vmswap_kb", c_uint32),
                     ("pfmajor", c_uint64),
                     ("pfminor", c_uint64),
                     ("scap_fdinfo", POINTER(scap_fdinfo)),
                     ("hh", UT_hash_handle)]
```

The last member of this structure marks it as hasheable. The problem comes when I call scap_get_proc_table function, next and prev pointers of UT_hash_handle are always evaluated as None. Other members like exe or comm have correct value for the first process on my system.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check the `sizeof()` each of the structures in Python vs. C.  It will help track down which structure has an error.